# Is Socket.io "connect" event even safe to listen to?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I've been skeptical about this for years. The common practice is making a `Socket` and **then** listening to its `"connect"` event. It doesn't sound very safe.

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
CONNECT: const socket = io(……);
// ← An asynchronous connection establishment might happen here, no?
LISTEN: socket.on("connect", ……);
```

It tries to establish a connection **as soon as** the `CONNECT` statement gets executed. What if it does, **before** `LISTEN`?

What makes such a practice safe to be used? What I believe is that just because it is two consecutive statements doesn't mean an **asynchronous** connection establishment cannot happen in-between. Are my thoughts wrong?

---

## EDIT: internal code investigation.

I've just read the source code of `socket.io-client` and drawn a conclusion that the only *code-wise* safe way to go is to turn the `autoConnect` option off for `io()` not to create a `Socket` that automatically tries to establish a connection, which leads to arbitrary (“possibly-untimely”) emission of the `"connect"` event. This requires a manual call to `socket.open()` but is safe.

Here's how it goes:

1. `io()` [creates a `Manager` instance](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/8372591652260f88987c467b94573a144ee4db63/lib/index.js#L56) and [calls `.socket()` of it](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/8372591652260f88987c467b94573a144ee4db63/lib/index.js#L67).
2. The `.socket()` [creates a new `Socket` instance](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/3020e455ab9a81341722e6c1e6cd8ef6b4b0ea28/lib/manager.js#L369) and [then binds **the `Manager`'s own** internal handlers (that is not users') for `"connecting"` and `"connect"` events](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/3020e455ab9a81341722e6c1e6cd8ef6b4b0ea28/lib/manager.js#L372-L375).
3. Since the `Socket`'s constructor [`.open()`s if `autoConnect`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/3020e455ab9a81341722e6c1e6cd8ef6b4b0ea28/lib/socket.js#L70), which [involves the immediate emission of a `"connecting"` event](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/3020e455ab9a81341722e6c1e6cd8ef6b4b0ea28/lib/socket.js#L109) and [the future emission of a `"connect"` event](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/3020e455ab9a81341722e6c1e6cd8ef6b4b0ea28/lib/socket.js#L335), the `Manager` [calls **its own** internal `"connecting"` event handler manually if `autoConnect`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/3020e455ab9a81341722e6c1e6cd8ef6b4b0ea28/lib/manager.js#L377-L381).

### Turned out `new Socket` never waits for you

I could not find any safe-guard gizmo (at least *code-wise*) to keep an `autoConnect`-ing `Socket` from establishing a `"connect"`-ion until corresponding handlers get attached.

### The internal implementation is also making this assumption

What's funny is that even `Manager` does this dangerous practice,

```
Manager.prototype.socket = function (nsp, opts) {
  var socket = this.nsps[nsp];
  if (!socket) {
    socket = new Socket(this, nsp, opts);
    this.nsps[nsp] = socket;
    var self = this;
    socket.on('connecting', onConnecting);
    socket.on('connect', function () {
      socket.id = self.generateId(nsp);
    });

    if (this.autoConnect) {
      // manually call here since connecting event is fired before listening
      onConnecting();
    }
  }

  function onConnecting () {
    if (!~indexOf(self.connecting, socket)) {
      self.connecting.push(socket);
    }
  }

  return socket;
};
```

making an assumption that a `Socket`, with the `autoConnect` option being `true` or not,

```
socket = new Socket(this, nsp, opts);
```

won't get to `"connect"` before

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
  socket.id = self.generateId(nsp);
});
```

.

Are there any good reasons to make this assumption, aside from “the code path to handler-attaching just looks shorter (“cheaper”) than that of connection establishment?” **How come this is not a *race condition*?**

Answer (score 0):

You need an EventEmitter before to attach a `connect` event, additionally the socket.io-client library manages this scenario, take a look on:

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/manager.js#L378

Comment: Do you mean an `EventEmitter` preliminarily `.on("connect")`'d? Say I had one, how do I specify it when I do `io(……)`? Would you please show me some examples?

Comment: This `const socket = io(……);` returns an `EventEmitter`, and then you can attach events to `socket` variable to listen to, when `connect` event is fired the callback is executed, if it's fired before to attach de event because of async code and `autoConnect` is true, the internal method `onConnecting` is called to perform the connection.

Comment: `io()` [creates a `Manager` instance](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/8372591652260f88987c467b94573a144ee4db63/lib/index.js#L56) and [calls `.socket()` of it](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/8372591652260f88987c467b94573a144ee4db63/lib/index.js#L67).

Comment: The `.socket()` [creates a new `Socket` instance](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/3020e455ab9a81341722e6c1e6cd8ef6b4b0ea28/lib/manager.js#L369) and [then binds **the `Manager`'s own** internal listeners (that is not users') for `"connecting"` and `"connect"` events](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/3020e455ab9a81341722e6c1e6cd8ef6b4b0ea28/lib/manager.js#L372-L375).

Comment: Since the `Socket`'s constructor [`.open()`s if `autoConnect`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/3020e455ab9a81341722e6c1e6cd8ef6b4b0ea28/lib/socket.js#L70), which [involves the emission of a `"connecting"` event](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/3020e455ab9a81341722e6c1e6cd8ef6b4b0ea28/lib/socket.js#L109), the `Manager` [calls **its own** internal `"connecting"` event listener manually if `autoConnect`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/3020e455ab9a81341722e6c1e6cd8ef6b4b0ea28/lib/manager.js#L377-L381).

Comment: I don't see any gizmo to deal with **users'** future-attached events here.

Comment: And `Manager`'s making an assumption for `"connect"`, too. I've made an edit for this to my question.